# How should I use navigation properties while writing a query using eSQL?

Tags: properties, navigation, entity-sql

I am trying to write a query using eSQL wherein my entity has got navigation properties. I am not able to include these navigation properties in the query, even though in Linq to SQL we have this (Include method).

How will it be possible in eSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
string esql = "Select value e from EFEntities.MyDataEntity as e";

ObjectQuery<Data.MyDataEntity> query = c.
    CreateQuery<Data.MyDataEntity>(esql).
    Include("MyNavigationProperty");

List<Data.MyDataEntity> entities = query.ToList();
```